# How do I add a UIButton into my UITableViewCell in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an existing UITableView that displays data and is working fine.

However I now want to add an info button into this UITableViewCell.

I added the UIButton directly into the TableViewCell in storyboard.  I then tried to declare this button as an outlet but I got the error

> "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

I read around the subject and decided to create a new subclass called "

```
import UIKit

class PersonalStatsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var personalStatsInfoButton: UIButton!

var selectedCellTitle: String?


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

As you can see I have declared the UIButton `personalStatsInfoButton` in this sub-class.

With more reading around the subject I believe I need to add something like:

```
personalStatsInfoButton.tag = indexPath.row
personalStatsInfoButton.addTarget(self, action: "infoButtonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and then have a function:

```
function infoButtonClicked(sender:UIButton){
      let infoCell = sender.tag
      print (infoCell)
}
```

My issue is I don't know whether I need to take all my existing tableView code and transfer it into the the new sub-class `PersonalStatsTableViewCell` or just the parts that deal with the info button.

Below is my existing VC code that initially deals with the TableView prior to adding in this new button.

```
import UIKit

class ShowCommunityViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var membersTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var communityName: UILabel!
var communityIsCalled: String?
var comIds =  [String]()
var communityId: Int?


var selectedCellTitle: String?
var cellId: Int?

var communityPlayerIds =  [String]()
var communityPlayers =  [String?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

 super.viewDidLoad()

    communityName.text = (communityIsCalled)
    self.membersTableView.delegate = self
    self.membersTableView.dataSource = self
    membersTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.communityPlayers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalStatsTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 12)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white // set to any colour
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    return cell

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedCellTitle = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    cellId = indexPath.row


}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.???.uk/???/specificCommunity.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "id=\(comIds[communityId!])";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                  if let arr = json?["players"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.communityPlayerIds = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}
                        self.communityPlayers = arr.flatMap { $0["user_name"]!}
                    self.membersTableView.reloadData()
                       print ("names: ",self.communityPlayers)
                    }

                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
        }
    task.resume()


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and what you are thinking is correct, you just need to change the following line.

Apart from what Arun B has said, you need to make sure xcode knows what kind of class `cell` will belong to.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalStatsTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
```

should be

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalStatsTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PersonalStatsTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put any code in your class `PersonalStatsTableViewCell` you can manage all the things from `ShowCommunityViewController` what you need to done is in your `cellForRowAt` method add this

```
cell.personalStatsInfoButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.personalStatsInfoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonClicked(sender:), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and add this function

```
function infoButtonClicked(sender:UIButton){
      let infoCell = sender.tag
      print (infoCell)
}
```

Comment: As Rajat says, you can do this without a custom table view cell class. Just set up the target/action of each button in your cellForRowAt() method. You can then either use the tag to return the index path, or use the frame.origin of the button to figure out the indexPath of the cell that contains the button.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the custom class is not set up properly. Make sure that `PersonalStatsTableViewCell` is set as the Custom class of the `UITableViewCell` in your storyboard.

[image]